# How to divide shape in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am new in Adobe Illustrator. This is my first assignment on it. I want to divide my shape

This is my shape

[image]

i want to divide this shape like following image
[image]

how i can do it?

Comment: Nice. This is way easier to answer than the previous question.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, your shape isn't created correctly, to get that perfect shape you need to use the Polar Grid Tool, set the width and the height (they should be the same), the Concentric Dividers to 0 and the Radial dividers to 6.

After that you need to create a simple Circle the size of the desired inner circle, select both shapes, center them Horizontally and Vertically and use Pathfinder > Divider then select the lines inside the small circle and delete them, you will end up with this:

[image]

After that, select the circle, give the lines a Stroke Weight equivalent to the gap you want between the "life cycles" objects and go ahead and Expand the entire circle.

All you need to do now is create another circle the exact H and W as the one you've keen working on and place it under, center them Horizontally and Vertically and then hit Pathfinder > Minus Front and delete the remaining inner circle:

[image]

**Answering your question in the comments**

> First you need to see what Height and Width the circle resulted from Polar Grid is,
>   for this, select the circle and check the Transform panel on your
>   right and it will show the position on the X and Y axes, and the W and
>   H of the circle. Create another circle of that exact W and H and fill
>   it with a color, say red (no outline).
>
> Now, right click on it, hover over Arrange and click Send To Back.
>   Select both circles and click both Horizontal and Vertical Align
>   Center then in the Pathfinder Panel, click Minus Front.

**Another Edit regarding your last question in the comments.**

> If you wanna place an image over the object and take it's shape in
>   Illustrator, you will use Clipping Mask. Just put the image
>   **UNDERNEATH** the shape you want to place it over, select both the desired shape and the image, go to Object > Clipping Mask > Make.

[image]

There are other ways of doing this but I find this the easiest.
Good luck!

Comment: No you dont need to use polar grid.

Comment: @joojaa Like I mentioned in the end, there are a lot of ways of doing this, you could even draw a circle and 3 lines, one that is vertical and the other two rotated to -/+60 degrees and you would still get the shape but I find this easier.

Comment: @Alin `All you need to do now is create another circle the exact H and W as the one you've keen working on and place it under, center them Horizontally and Vertically and then hit Pathfinder > Minus Front and delete the remaining inner circle:` can you please explain it for me... I am not able to do this. How i can do it?

Comment: @sunny , I've explained it in the update of my answer (down). If you need help with anything else, comment.

Comment: @Alin i want to add images inside

Comment: @sunny , If you wanna do this in Illustrator, you will use the same principle as in my answer here : http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/58750/48529 Clipping Mask. Just pun the image UNDERNEATH the shape you want to place it over, select both the shape and the image, go to Object > Clipping Mask > Make.

Comment: @Alin How i can make image shape in triangle like in my circle?

Comment: @sunny I have already answered that, CLIPPING MASK. See last image update for step by step.

Comment: @sunny , if this answered your question, please mark it as correct so it doesn't appear in the Unanswered section in the search. Thank you.